# Accessing files from a Java Applet

Tags: java, security, file-io, applet, runtime.exec

I'm building this desktop application in java that reads input from `Standard.in` (or more specifically  `FileInputStream`), I want to (or I am planning to) make it into a JApplet.

I'm not an expert when it comes to web-programming, so the question is, is it possible for a java applet to access local files? And better yet, can it execute system calls (i.e., `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`) ?

Comment: *"I want to (or I am planning to) make it into a JApplet."*  Why not a `JFrame` launched from a link?  It will still need to be signed/trusted, but deployment is easier for you and the user experience is better.

Comment: That's sort of what I originally thought(ie., just give the user the installer), but from my experience, people tend to do everything via the browser nowadays!

Answer (score 1):

An applet would need to be digitally signed by you and trusted by the end user when prompted, before it could access the local file-system or use `exec` to start a process.

Comment: I see. So it is possible? (I can obviously get the app signed and all that)